# Hole size of BGA stencil

Tags: bga, stencil

I need to design a stencil for reballing.
0.76 is the diameter of the ball.

What should be the size of each hole in the stencil?

I was thinking about 0.8mm. Is that correct?

Comment: What does the datasheet for the part say? There will be recommended designs from the manufacturer somewhere.

Comment: Don't "think," read the datasheet.  Any good datasheet will have footprint and mask details well-documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very complex matter and a higly professional task.
Please take care that (in normal cases), BGA pad dimensions will mainly depend from the BGA pitch.
Once the pads dimension is defined, normally the stencil aperture should always be smaller than the pad.
In case you need more solder volume, you have to increase the stencil thickness.
The complexity of the design depends either the BGA pads are soldermask-defined or not.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. There is no need to `@` ping the OP (original poster) as that is automatic when you post an answer. You had a space after the `@` so it wasn't going to work anyway. The syntax is `@username`.